# Does ConnectionsClient.sendPayload() encrypt the payload?

Tags: google-nearby, man-in-the-middle

If I send data between Android devices using [`ConnectionsClient.sendPayload()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/connection/ConnectionsClient.html#sendPayload(java.lang.String,%20com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.Payload)), will the data be encrypted in transit, or can it be intercepted (over wifi or Bluetooth)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you confirm the token provided in ConnectionLifecycleCallback.onConnectionInitiated() on both devices before calling ConnectionsClient.acceptConnection(), the data is safely encrypted.